# Github Copilot stopt working in vs studio

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I used copilot for 1-2 months, and a few days ago
it stopt working in wpf but in console it works

Comment: for your information, if you you receive an answer which "realy helpt" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956599/getting-text-from-a-custom-usercontrol-using-binding?noredirect=1#comment128870548_72956599) - you don't delete entire post, you accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). if you read my answer, applied it, and then rewrote the question with working code, which invalidated the answer, and then deleted the post - I won't bother with any suggestions ever again even if it is absolutely trivial

Comment: @ASh Sorry bro, I made a mistake cus I didn't know how to handle а question please forgive me.